# WatchOS 2 and Xcode 7: App does not launch on the Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode7-beta4

My Watch app builds and runs fine when I launch it through Xcode 7 (beta 4) on the Watch, but when I try to launch the app on the Watch by tapping on its icon, it never launches and shows the spinning circle for ~1 minutes and then goes back to the watch-face.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ran into the same issue. Solution found here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9607

1. Run app on device from xcode. Wait for loading daisy on watch
2. Force quit app **before the app finishes loading**. (Hold friends button until power options displays, then hold friends button again until app closes.)
3. Stop debugging on Xcode
4. exit xcode (do not reboot/restart xcode)
5. run app on watch. It should run now.
6. if this does not work start from step 1 again.

Comment: The first time I tried this solution it didn't work. The trick for me was to make sure I force quit the application before it finished loading (while the loading daisy was still on the screen).

Comment: You are right.  Force-quit before loading is finished is key.  It works now.

Comment: Please make sure you file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com about this, including all available logging that you have.

Comment: This seems to work exactly once. That is, if you follow this procedure, tapping on the watch app launches your app once.  But, you wouldn't be able to re-launching on the watch more than once until you follow the same process.  For the 4th beta, this is pretty lame.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. It works for me now. Was driving me nuts. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't work with beta 5 anymore. What's going on with Apple?

Comment: lol, I'm getting this problem in the production version, 8.1. It took me way longer than it should have to display "Hello, World!".